# How do I add trigger to an AWS Lambda function using AWS SDK PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, events, aws-lambda

I have an existing AWS Lambda function, I test it on AWS console and it works great. my application is creating S3 bucket automatically so I need the add dynamically the trigger to the buckets.

I can't find this in the documentation of AWS SDK PHP.
Please help...

Comment: can you post your code

Answer (score 1):

To call a Lambda function you'll need to use the [`invoke`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Lambda.LambdaClient.html#_invoke) method.

```
$result = $client->invoke([
    'FunctionName' => 'MyFunctionName', // REQUIRED
    'Payload' => 's3-bucket-name'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't truly understand your question. The more details that you provide the better will be the responses.

S3 does not publish an event on bucket creation. S3 does have events for objects inside a bucket (PUT, POST, DELETE, etc but not GET).

The only service that I can think of that would detect bucket creation is CloudTrail. You would then have to filter every API event and then call your Lambda on bucket create. Enabling CloudTrail is a good idea and is enabled by default for all new AWS accounts.

You could create an object inside the bucket after creating the bucket. This could trigger your Lambda function. However, you would need to filter that also as you would get an event for every object create event.

Probably the best solution is John Veldboom's answer where your code just calls Lambda after creating the bucket.

Note: you mention that you are creating buckets dynamically. You have a limit of 100 buckets per AWS account (which can be increased). I hope your design is not creating a lot of buckets. A better approach is to create folders inside a bucket.

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is [`createEventSourceMapping()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-lambda-2015-03-31.html#createeventsourcemapping).

After you create the S3 bucket, you can then call this function to add a mapping from your new S3 bucket to your Lambda function.

To help you out with the parameters, try using [`getEventSourceMapping()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-lambda-2015-03-31.html#geteventsourcemapping) or [`listEventSourceMappings()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-lambda-2015-03-31.html#listeventsourcemappings) to see your existing event source mappings to your function.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what you're trying to achieve.

You can call the [createBucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#createbucket%20createBucket) method asynchronously, and *then* `invoke` your lambda function with the SDK if there is no specific triggering event for that:

```
$client->createBucketAsync([/* ... */])->then(
   function($success_response) {
      $client->invoke(
        'FunctionName'   => 'λ_Name',
        'InvocationType' => 'Event',
        'Payload'        => json_encode( $some_data )
   },
   function($error) {
      // something went wrong see $error
   }
);
```

That would trigger your lambda function after the bucket was successfully created.